# in LUA - having found a variable of type "function" in _G how to pass a parameter to it

Tags: function, lua, global

I have successfully found functions in a table within _G and,  for those that do not expect arguments, I've called them with a syntax such as:

```
a = _G[t] [f] ()
```

but some functions are expecting arguments and I have tried to pass them using

```
a = _G[t] [f] (x)
```

but the error message from LUA seems to say that the called function has not received "x".

My question therefore is, if the function is defined as

```
function t:f (arg)
```

how do I give it an argument to process when I have the text strings for t and f ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function defined like

```lua
function t:f(arg)
```

has a implicit first arg of `self` so the definition is actually the same as:

```lua
function t.f(self, arg)
```

So with this, when you call `a = _G["t"]["f"](x)` you are passing in `x` as self and `arg` is set to nil. To call this properly you need to do

```lua
_G["t"]["f"](_G["t"], arg);
```

---

Some example code so you can see this in action

```lua
t = {}

function t:f(arg)
    print(self, arg)
end

_G["t"]["f"]("test")         -- "test   nil"
_G["t"]["f"](_G["t"],"test") -- "table: 00e09750    test"
```